# How to force y position of one branch in d3 sankey plugin?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I would like to force one branch of sankey diagram to be on top.

Instead of diagram like this:
[image: Current diagram]

would like to generate diagram where nodes 1, 2, 7, 15, 10 and 14 are always on top:
[image: Modified diagram]

Link to fiddle with current code: http://jsfiddle.net/w5jfp9t0/1/

```
var margin = {top: 1, right: 1, bottom: 6, left: 1};
var width = 1052 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d); },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("#chart_sankey").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var sankey = d3.sankey()
                         .nodeWidth(35)
                         .nodePadding(10)
                         .size([width, height]);

var path = sankey.link();

raw = '{"nodes":[{"name":"Node 1"},{"name":"Node 2"},{"name":"Node 3"},{"name":"Node 4"},{"name":"Node 5"},{"name":"Node 6"},{"name":"Node 7"},{"name":"Node 8"},{"name":"Node 9"},{"name":"Node 10"},{"name":"Node 11"},{"name":"Node 12"},{"name":"Node 13"},{"name":"Node 14"},{"name":"Node 15"}],"links":[{"source":9,"target":13,"value":25},{"source":14,"target":9,"value":37},{"source":14,"target":11,"value":16},{"source":14,"target":12,"value":8},{"source":14,"target":10,"value":68},{"source":6,"target":14,"value":154},{"source":6,"target":8,"value":40},{"source":1,"target":6,"value":345},{"source":1,"target":7,"value":66},{"source":1,"target":3,"value":17},{"source":1,"target":4,"value":25},{"source":1,"target":5,"value":117},{"source":0,"target":1,"value":692},{"source":0,"target":2,"value":19}]}';
data = JSON.parse(raw);

sankey.nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .layout(32);

var link = svg.append("g")
            .selectAll(".link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
            .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

var nodes = data.nodes;

var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
    .on("drag", dragmove));

sankey.relayout();

node.filter(function(d) { return d.value != 0; }) // append text only if node value is not zero
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
  .append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

node.filter(function(d) { return d.value != 0; }) // append text only if node value is not zero
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", -6)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", null)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .filter(function(d) { return d.x == 0; }) // at first column append text after column
    .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
    .attr("text-anchor", "start");

function dragmove(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + (d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))) +  ")");
  sankey.relayout();
  link.attr("d", path);
}
```

What do I need to change to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note**
To be honest, I never used that plugin. I don't see an option to get the desired behaviour directly - thus I looked at the source of sankey.js to make the adjustments. Below I show how I'd modify - you might want to do it more thoroughly :)

**Idea**

Looking at the code of sankey.js, you see that the nodes are placed (y-direction) using the `center` function:

```
function center(node) {
  return node.y + node.dy / 2;
}
```

As I don't see a parameter to change that behaviour, you can change it to:

```
function center(node) {
  return 0;
}
```

If you then also revert the sorting order:

```
function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
  return b.y - a.y;
}
```

you get the following picture:

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you! I hope I will figure out how to move node 14 on top too :).

Comment: Don't be too quick to accept :) maybe other people have different approaches. Also, you might want to play with the sorting function (maybe base it on some other attribute) to get other effects. Good luck! (I kinda kept my answer "open ended" deliberately :) )

Comment: Your solution is good enough for the moment, but you are right that others could contribute different solutions. :)

Comment: sure thing! if there are no better solutions, don't forget to accept it later on :) Also, if you make a clean implementation of a sorting function, feel free to add it here or add a new answer! Good luck