# Vertically sort each subset of branches in D3 Sankey diagram

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, svg, sankey-diagram

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zpgt1aq0/3/

I'd like to order the nodes in my sankey diagram by value for each "column" of the diagram.

Here is an example of the ordering I'd like to display (created manually for the time being): 
[image: Sorted Sankey example]

However, this is what the default sort gives me:
[image]

Some researching led me to the following two questions:

[How to force y position of one branch in d3 sankey plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121764/how-to-force-y-position-of-one-branch-in-d3-sankey-plugin)

[Vertical sort of nodes in D3 Sankey diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777116/vertical-sort-of-nodes-in-d3-sankey-diagram)

but neither of these are exactly what I'm looking for.

I imagine this has to do with a combination of the `ascendingDepth()` function and the `removeCollisions()` piece of the `computeNodeDepths()` function, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to proceed.